# Gráfico Excel usando Phpsreadsheet

Tags: php

Alguien tiene algún ej de cómo hacer un grafico en Excel usando esta librería , todos los ejemplos que están en la doc no me funcionan

Comment: Hola  Maur Icio
, bienvenido, la idea detrás del funcionamiento de este sitio, es ayudar a los programadores a resolver los problemas que se encuentran durante la creación de aplicaciones, muéstranos que has realizado, que problemas tienes, y trabajaremos juntos para solventarlos, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de Bienvenida para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!.

Comment: estoy usando la libreria phpspreadsheet, 
aparentemente tengo un error en los dataseries,
$dataSeriesValues = [
    new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_NUMBER, 'Graficos!$A$2:$B$5', null, 4),
    new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_NUMBER, 'Graficos!$B$2:$B$5', null, 4),
    new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_NUMBER, 'Graficos!$C$2:$C$5', null, 4),
    new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_NUMBER, 'Graficos!$D$2:$D$5', null, 4),
];
usando un ej q encontre, pero no dibuja nada , ni da ningun error